# chrome extension: null parameter error on querySelector on content script

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that will interact with twitch drops and notify me if the drop is ready for collection. I am injecting a content script fetch attributes of a particular element by its class but it shows **Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')**.
Here is my content.js code:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".juerA");
var val = element.getAttribute('value');
console.log(val);
```

If I run the same code on the console, it works fine. I have tried using *"run_at" : "document_end"* but it doesn't work. I have also checked if the extension works if I change the matches of the content script with other web pages and it works.

Comment: Use MutationObserver or setInterval.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks it is working but can you tell me why it was making a problem?

Comment: The site is creating the element using its scripts after the initial page is loaded.